# Accessing element in pop-up Selenium Web Auto testing

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I am using selenium for web automation. I can login other also. But, in one page of web, I click to open pop-up. After that, I access checkbox in that pop-up. For that procedure, selenium cannot do. I would like to know how to access that particular id. What am I missing to do?

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/2u7n6md.png]

Answer (score 0):

After clicked on the Pop-up, you have to select that pop-up and then click on radio button
In windowsID you have to write id of the popup

```
selectPopUp | windowsid
click       | id=gropup
```

Comment: I dun need to write anything in Selenium I guess. I just need to press record and replay. Command, target are also auto key in and I think nothing is missing there. How should I do?

Comment: Some commands you have to write manually in log panel of selenium ide because selenium IDE do not record all the commands

Comment: I think it record correctly. But, when I run the program, it cannot acceses to id=groups_1_check. How should I do?

Comment: it can not access id=groups_1_check because it open in a new popup window and in your code you do not select this pop-up. if a new window or popup is open then it record by selenium but when you replay that script then it fail on the new pop-up palce for that you have to write code manual in the selenium IDE